# How to add Keycloak cusom member_role relationship

Tags: oauth-2.0, roles, openid-connect, keycloak, rbac

**Is there a way to setup a relationship as follows using Keycloak?**

1. Roles -- can have many -- Premissions
2. Projects -- have all roles associated to them -- Roles
3. Users -- can be a member of many -- Projects   (member)
4. and a User is given a **MemberRole** meaning that they can have different roles on different projects

Therefore if we have:

- Roles: Tester (permission create_issue, view_issue), Developer (permission view_issue)
- Projects: Project1 and Project2
- User: Person1 and Person2

Then Person1 can have the role of Tester on Project1, and role of Developer on Project2 which means:

1. Person1:  Project1 - permissions create_issue, view_issue  (from Tester Role)
2. Person1:  Project2 - permissions view_issue   (from Developer Role)

I have tried various setups in Keycloak, the closet I got was doing the following, however the token always includes roles to the lowest level. I am therefore unable to tell which if they have this permission for Project1 or Project2. 
eg in Keycloak: 
 - Under roles of a client I setup four roles namely create_issue, view_issue 
 - and tester which is a composite role containing both create_issue, view_issue 
 - and developer which is a composite role containing only view_issue

I then setup groups
 - project1 with nested groups of 
 - project1developer (which is mapped to the developer role above)
 - project1tester    (which is mapped to the tester role above)

- project2 with nested groups of
- project2developer (which is mapped to the developer role above)
- project2tester    (which is mapped to the tester role above)

I then assigned user Person1 to the project1developer group & project2tester group

When I request a Token for this user the response includes the following:

```
...
"resource_access": {
    "redmine": {
      "roles": [
        "create_issue",
        "view_issue",
        "tester",
        "developer"
      ]
    }
}
...
"group_membership": [
    "/project1/project1developer",
    "/project2/project2tester"
  ],
...
```

I am not able to tell which group the create_issue role comes from is it against project1 or project2.

**Is there a way to setup a relationship described above in Keycloak (I am missing the MemeberRole configuration)?**